# d3.js csv data filter contain a word

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I have a CSV file like this

```
product, year

Apple Iphone11,2019
Apple Iphone11 pro,2019
Apple Iphone11 pro max,2019
Samsung Galaxy S10+,2019
Samsung Galaxy Note10+, 2019
Sony Xperia 1,2019
Sony Xperia 5,2019
```

how can I filter by a word(Apple, Samsung, Sony) with a bar chart
the graph will display the amount of the products and company name 
for example, (x,y) will be (Apple,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a map

   `const brand2occurrences = new Map();`
2. for each row of the csv (don't forget that the first line is the header) split by "," and then split the first value by " "

   `const currentBrand = currentRow.split(",")[0].split(" ")[0];`
   so that now you have the brand name
3. take the number of times you've entered this brand until now

   `const currentOccurrencesOfThisBrand = brand2occurrences.get(currentBrand);`
4. update the value of the occurrences (if it is the first time that you enter the brand then the counter starts at 1, otherwise you update it) and save

   `brand2occurrences.set(currentBrand, (currentOccurrencesOfThisBrand ? currentOccurrencesOfThisBrand++ : 1))`

now you have a map (BrandName, BrandOccurrences) as you want